# Grunt watch doesn't watch _theme.less and custom less file

Tags: magento2, error, custom, less, grunt

That's my css/source file structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tNxJ.png

I made **grunt clean, theme exec, theme less, watch**.
Watch is responsive to any less file changes accept of **_theme.less** and **local.less** located level us (css/local.less). **Local.less** was already added to **theme.js**:

**files: [
  'css/styles-m', 
  'css/styles-l', 
  'css/local'
],**

local and _theme compiling well with **grunt less** but not responsive for **grunt watch**. The problem is related ot this two file only, all others including modules extends are watching by grunt ok.

Any ideas?

---

Grunt less output:

Running "less:base" (less) task
`File pub/static/frontend/MaxTheme/base/en_US/css/styles-m.css created: 307.72 kB → 529.6 kB
File pub/static/frontend/MaxTheme/base/en_US/css/styles-l.css created: 51.13 kB → 89.83 kB
File pub/static/frontend/MaxTheme/base/en_US/css/local.css created: 25 B → 242 B`

---

UPD: Just checked */pub/static*, the two less files placed not as symlinks, but as regular less files.

Answer (score 3):

I looked into it … AND! **finally the solution** is too easy:

The *Client Side* and *Grunt* Compilation of *.less files **REQUIRES** the 
`@import` directive to contain the file extension:

use `@import '_test.less'` instead of `@import '_test'`

If **ALL** `@imports` in **ALL** imported files do that: you'll get a symlink to all files AND grunt watch watches! ;-)

---

According to:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#fedg_css-import

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my research finished and looks like that's M2 bug.

**Details:**

**_theme.less** have the **@imports** in the header and that's the problem. I made theme **exec** and got **_theme.less** file copy of the same size in **/pub/static**, not symlink. I removed all **@imports**, **exec**, I got zero size symlink to **_theme.less** for now. I repeated tests 3-4 times. 100% dependency.

Ok, going forward.

My existent **@imports** format:

> > @import '_buttons_extend';

format was changed to:

> > @import url('_buttons_extend');

That's the miracle, I got symlink for now.

Run **grunt less:theme-name**, got

> > File "pub\static\frontend\MaxTheme\base\en_US\css\source_theme.less" changed.
> >     Running "less:base" (less) task
> >     FileError: '_buttons_extend.less' wasn't found in pub\static\frontend\MaxTheme\base\en_US\css\source_theme.less on line 3, column 1:
> >     2 @import '_vars';
> >     3 @import '_buttons_extend';
> >     4 @import 'components/_footer';
> >     Warning: Error compiling pub/static/frontend/MaxTheme/base/en_US/css/styles-m.less Use --force to continue.

But **_buttons_extend** locates in the same directory as **_theme.less**. I posted my dir structure screenshot above. So that's two ways: to live with the exec or less/watch error. I prefer the first one. Just to keep **@imports** in **_theme.less** and reexec theme if I added some **@import** there.